# How to read PDF file and generate PDF/A-3?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfa

I am trying to read data from pdf file and writing to PDF/A-3. But somehow it is not working. I used [This link](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/archiving-and-accessibility-itext5/pdfa-3) for reference. I have changed MIME type to **application/pdf** and tried as per the above reference. How can i create PDF/A-3 from pdf file?

Comment: Your question is weird. It can't be answered because it sounds as: "Please tell me how to make carrots from carrot soup; I have turned on the radio but it doesn't help." I can't make any sense of what you are asking, nor of what you've tried. Why do you think you can create a PDF/A-3 document automatically out of any PDF that can be found in the wild? For instance: how are you going to deal with missing fonts? Also: why PDF/A-3? Why not PDF/A-2? Does the original PDF have attachments? I'm voting to close your question. I'll retract my vote if you improve the question.

Comment: The link you *used for reference* shows how to generate a new PDF/A document from scratch, not how to change an existing, arbitrary pdf into a PDF/A (which as @Bruno indicated usually is not possible).